# Eclipse context menus are cut off or don't show

Tags: eclipse, windows, ide

Hi Using eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426 on windows 7. After 2-3 hours of continues use some of the context menus on right click just disappears.
Restarting helps and they will be restored so i have restart 3-4 times a day.
also tried to restore perspective from windows menu but didn't help. another thing i observed is that it's not just the context menu items, some of the short keys are also not working like - ctrl+C, ctrl+V, del etc.

Comment: Well how about moving to a release that isn't 3 years old. Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2) has just been released.

Comment: well that shouldn't be the only option.